# Getting the contents inside an html tag

Tags: jquery

I have some simple code below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("h1").click(function(){
    console.log((this));
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<p>If you click test, I will toggle.</p>

</body>
```

If I click on test I can toggle the visibility of the p tag. At the same time I am writing `<h1>test</h1>` to the console. What I want is to write the word test only to the console. How do I do that? Nothing I tried works.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
console.log((this));
```

With

```
console.log($(this).text());
```

Comment: I used this one. I actually had this and somehow it didn't work at first before I posted to this forum.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, it will give you the text only.

```
$(function() {
  $("h1").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

You can see the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/9CzWH/).

Comment: yeah, .text() for text, .html() for html :)

Comment: how did this improve on the other `.text()` answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

Comment: .text() is better in this case I think.

Comment: I guess, I have always used `.html()`, do you have a link why? performance, readability?

Comment: From the jQuery website: "Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents". Furthermore...it strips out any HTML tags, which in this case might be what the poster wanted.

Comment: Alright, point taken, I'll use that in the future, thank you @Baszz